# selection from maxmind db

Tags: t-sql, maxmind

I Have a maxmind DB with 2 tables, geoIP and geoLOC

then I have a list of some 10000 cities/towns and I want to get lat and lng of each city to display on a map

I would avoid to use a 10000 loops to get the details:
I thought it was better to use the `IN` statement of T-SQL and put all the cities name
but problem is that almost all large cities have more than 1 reference and therefore I get some duplicated results

I tried using distinct:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM geoloc l 
JOIN geoip i
ON l.geoname_Id = (SELECT TOP 1 i.geoname_id
                   WHERE l.locale_code='en'
                       AND country_iso='US'
                       AND l.city IN ('seattle','boston','detroit'))
```

but I get 14284 results instead of 3, while

which is the way to achieve such result, and, can be this solution more performing or could be better to use the for next loop?

here Tables definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.GeoLoc (
geoname_Id bigint NULL,
locale_code nvarchar(5) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
continent_code nvarchar(2) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
continent_name nvarchar(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
country_iso nvarchar(2) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
country_name nvarchar(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
sub1_iso nvarchar(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
sub1_name nvarchar(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
sub2_iso nvarchar(130) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
sub2_name nvarchar(150) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
city nvarchar(255) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
metro_code nvarchar(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
time_zone nvarchar(150) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.GeoIP (
sIP bigint NULL,
eIP bigint NULL,
startIp nvarchar(20) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
geoname_id bigint NULL,
rc_geonameid nvarchar(30) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
rcg nvarchar(20) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
isProxy bit NULL,
isSat bit NULL,
postalcode nvarchar(20) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
lat nvarchar(20) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
lng nvarchar(20) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL
)
INSERT INTO @GeoLoc(geoname_Id,locale_code,country_iso,sub1_iso,city)
VALUES 
(1,'en','US','WA','seattle'),
(2,'en','US','MA','boston'),
(3,'en','US','MI','detroit'),
(4,'en','US','VA','boston'),
(5,'en','US','TX','boston'),
(6,'en','US','WA','Z'),
(7,'en','US','NY','boston'),
(8,'en','US','GA','boston')

INSERT INTO @GeoIP(geoname_id,lat,lng)
VALUES
(1,47.6062,-122.3321),
(1,47.6062,-122.3321),
(1,47.7396,-122.3426),
(1,47.4323,-121.8034),
(1,47.6738,-122.3419),
(1,47.4323,-121.8034),
(1,47.6062,-122.3321),
(2,42.6207,-78.7213),
(2,42.6207,-78.7213),
(2,42.6207,-78.7213),
(2,42.6207,-78.7213),
(3,42.3523,-83.0271),
(3,42.3314,-83.0457),
(3,42.3539,-83.2120),
(3,42.3314,-83.0457),
(3,42.3756,-83.1085)
```

therefore geoname_id in geoIP is not univoque since there are many records with same geoname_ID (both because there are many IP blocks referred to same city, and because, for some cities the resolution is at postalcode level, therefore there are also different lat and lng with the same geoname_ID (for our use the first we found can be acceptable).
But there is a further issue that has arisen: Seattle in GeoName is present only 1 time, but Detroit is present twice and Boston is present 4 times: since there is a city named Boston both in Georgia, Virginia, Massachusetts and New York and this, I presume makes the query too complicated :-(

Comment: Can you post the table definition and a few lines of sample data please.

Comment: You need to put your where clause also outside the clamps:

 WHERE l.locale_code='en'
                       AND country_iso='US'
                       AND l.city IN ('seattle','boston','detroit')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand - you want a record per city with a lat-long value.
Please keep in mind that in the MaxMind raw data, there are multiple entries per city for each postal code. Each with its Lat and Long values.

```
SELECT GL.geoname_Id, GL.city, LatLong.Lat, LatLong.Long
FROM GeoLoc GL with(NOLOCK)
OUTER APPLY (SELECT Top(1) Lat,Long from GeoIP GI WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE GI.geoname_id = GL.geoname_id order by GI.geoname_id) LatLong
WHERE GL.locale_code = 'en' 
  AND GL.countru_iso = 'US'
  AND GL.city IN ('seattle','boston','detroit')
```

Comment: Yes, right, and your solution solves the Postal Code Issue.. but there is still another problem: Cities with same name but in different States:
boston for example is present 4 times (New York,Virginia,Massachusetts,Georgia)... :-(

Comment: So what is the intended result set ?  I went according to what you posted in the question.  For instance - which Boston do you want ?  You can always add the State fiewld to the select or to the where clause.

Comment: Well I need the "right" Boston..
Yes I can add a State Field or in the where clause, but do not understand how to handle:
I should put the State in the IN clause like 
    `  IN ('seattle, WA', 'boston, MA', 'detroit, MI') ` but this is not possibile.. 

Perhaps only solution is to iterate the SQL query for each city with a where clause and not use the IN statement..

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what your after, but i hope that one of the below will be what your looking for.

If not then use the below examples to help explain your problem better.
If you could give me better data based on my examples than that would help a lot.  Also an example with results you want, and what results you are getting.

```
DECLARE @GeoLoc TABLE
(
   geoname_Id bigint,   --PK
   locale_code nvarchar(5),
   continent_code nvarchar(2),
   continent_name nvarchar(50),
   country_iso nvarchar(2),
   country_name nvarchar(100),
   sub1_iso nvarchar(100),
   sub1_name nvarchar(100),
   sub2_iso nvarchar(130),
   sub2_name nvarchar(150),
   city nvarchar(255),
   metro_code nvarchar(100),
   time_zone nvarchar(150)
)

INSERT INTO @GeoLoc(geoname_Id,locale_code,country_iso,city)
VALUES 
   (1,'en','US','seattle'),
   (2,'en','US','boston'),
   (3,'en','US','detroit'),
   (4,'en','US','X'),
   (5,'en','US','Y'),
   (6,'en','US','Z') 


DECLARE @GeoIP TABLE
(
   sIP bigint,
   eIP bigint,
   startIp nvarchar(20),
   geoname_id bigint,   --FK
   rc_geonameid nvarchar(30),
   rcg nvarchar(20),
   isProxy bit,
   isSat bit,
   postalcode nvarchar(20),
   lat nvarchar(20),
   lng nvarchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO @GeoIP(geoname_id,lat,lng)
VALUES
   (1,1,2),
   (2,1,2),
   (3,5,6)  


--Each cities location
------------------------------
SELECT      GP.lat,GP.lng,GL.city
FROM            @GeoLoc AS GL
INNER JOIN  @GeoIP AS GP ON GL.geoname_Id = GP.geoname_id
--Filter here WHERE         GL.city IN ('')

--Each location only once and one city name (The last one alphabetically)
------------------------------
SELECT      GP.lat,GP.lng,MAX(GL.city)
FROM            @GeoLoc AS GL
INNER JOIN  @GeoIP AS GP ON GL.geoname_Id = GP.geoname_id
--Filter here WHERE         GL.city IN ('')
GROUP BY        GP.lat,GP.lng

--Each location only once and all city names but only one result per location
------------------------------
SELECT      GP.lat,GP.lng,(SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + city FROM @GeoLoc AS GL INNER JOIN @GeoIP AS GP2 ON GL.geoname_Id = GP2.geoname_id WHERE GP.lat = GP2.lat AND GP.lng = GP2.lng ORDER BY GL.city FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''))
FROM            @GeoIP AS GP
INNER JOIN  @GeoLoc AS GL ON GP.geoname_id = GL.geoname_Id
--Filter here WHERE         GL.city IN ('')
GROUP BY        GP.lat,GP.lng
```